# What specifically is the "autonomous" component in the Paper Plasma: Scalable Autonomous Smart Contracts

Tags: plasma

The term "Autonomous" brings to mind Autonomous Driving / Driveless Car where cars drive on their own.

I read the paper Plasma: Scalable Autonomous Smart Contracts. I understood the Scalable part. However, the Autonomous part was a bit harder to understand. In total, autonomous was mentioned 8 times in the paper.

Question: What specifically does the term "autonomous" in the Paper Plasma: Scalable Autonomous Smart Contracts refer to?

Isn't smart contracts by its very nature autonomous? i.e., contracts which are self-enforcing (self-driving).

Would prefixing the term autonomous to Smart Contracts be unnecessary since Smart Contract by its very nature and design is autonomous? If autonomous is not an unnecessary prefix, in the context of the paper, what specifically then does the term autonomous refer to?

Thanks!